# If $2^{2x-1}$ = $(\frac{1}{5})^x$ and $\log 2 = a$ prove that: $x=\frac{a}{a+1}$

Tags: functions, logarithms

This is my working out:

$2^{2x} \times 2^{-1} = (5^{-1})^x$

$\log 2^{2x-1} = \log 5^{-x}$

$2x-1 \log 2 = -x\log5$

$2x-1\times a = -x\log5$

At this point, I got stuck.

Comment: Hint: express $\log 5$ in terms of $a$.

Comment: Your first line differs from the title.  Both need some parentheses.  The left side of the title reads as $2^2x-1=4x-1$.  The left side of the top line reads as $2^2*x2^{-1}=2x$.  I am sure neither is what you had in mind.  Please clarify.

Comment: Can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: Use $\LaTeX$ to edit your question otherwise people will have a hard time understanding it. Here's a quick guide : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry everyone, I fixed the issues with the formatting.

Comment: See my comment following lone student's answer.  Perhaps the problem composer made an oversight in not specifying the base of the logarithm, or perhaps you omitted that critical piece of information.  Going forward, with your future mathSE questions, please proofread your questions for clarity, possible missing information, and possible ambiguities.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm so sorry. We were taught that when there's no specified base number, it is automatically 10. I assumed everyone was taught in that way. Many apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2^{2x-1}=5^{-x}$$

$$\begin{align}&\implies (2x-1)\log 2=-x \log 5 \\
&\implies\frac{1-2x}{x}=\frac {\log 5}{\log 2} \\
&\implies \frac 1x-2=\frac {\log 5}{\log 2} \\
&\implies \frac 1x=\frac{2\log 2+\log 5}{\log 2}\\
&\implies x=\frac{\log 2}{2\log 2+\log 5}=\frac{\log 2}{\log 20}\end{align}$$

---

If you mean $\lg$ instead of $\log$, then you have:

$$x=\frac{\lg 2}{\lg 20}=\frac{\lg 2}{1+\lg 2}.$$

Comment: The base of log is $10$, so modifying your last step answers the question.

Comment: For what it's worth, the original assertion is true if and only if the (unstated) base of the logarithm is $(10)$, in the OP's question.

Comment: @Martund I edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @user2661923 I moved to base $10$.

Comment: @lonestudent Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The *concealed* point of my comment to you, was that (in my opinion), your original analysis was spot on.  I regard asking the person who answers the question to try to use *reverse-engineering* to determine the problem composer's intent as *above and beyond...*.